# Partial static attribute binding with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to have a partial static attribute binding with Ember.js?

It should be similar to the following example:

```
<img class="" {{bind-attr src='App.Data.staticResourceUrl/iceAndFire.jpg'}}>
```

Thank you and, if you need addititional information just let me know.

**Edit:**

Of course you can implement it as a view like this:

```
App.StaticImage = Ember.TextField.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, {
tagName: 'img',
attributeBindings: ['src', 'path'],

src: function() {
    return App.Data.get('staticResourceUrl')+'/'+this.get('path');
}.property('path')
});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{view "App.StaticImage" path="/Images/deathlyHallows.jpg"}}
```

If you know a better solution I would be glad to know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property isn't going to update on you you can just inject it unbound.

```
<img class="" src='{{unbound App.Data.staticResourceUrl}}/iceAndFire.jpg'>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AwACotA/1/edit